# Highcharts in mvc 4, many categories

Tags: highcharts

I built a graph using Highcharts receive data from the database, but get a lot of graphics categories. what do I need to do so that the categories not covered each other?

```
   DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
     .SetXAxis(new XAxis
     {

        Categories = date1

     })
     .SetSeries(new Series
     {

         Data = new Data( _objval )
     });


        return View(chart);
```

result
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/draHE.png

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) paramter